# Possession of a TLD domain name by a company that has registered the same name in United States Patent and Trademark Office

Tags: trademark, domain-name

Suppose that a person A owns a TLD domain(Top level domain) similar to the .com extension registered by another company in the United States Patent and Trademark Office. Suppose that the person wants to use the domain for a recently stated business.

Suppose that both sites are active in the same field and there are no other copyright infringements such as similarity in Logo or UI.

A's new business's scope of activity is national and nationwide and will not be international

*A's  domain: xyz.es*

*Other domain: xyz.com*

If A starts a business with this TLD domain, can a foreign company owning a similar .com domain take over A's TLD domain by suing A in ICANN or any other judicial authority?

Comment: relevant: https://www.debevoise.com/insights/publications/2020/06/supreme-court-holds-booking

Comment: Is A's business in Spain, in the United States, or in some other country?

Comment: Some introductory information is found in articles on cybersquatting which is what this kind of dispute is called. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cybersquatting I have removed the copyright tag as it does not apply in this context. You can't copyright a domain name. ICANN has an arbitration like process which is the main enforcement tool, but not the exclusive one.